# Jquery $get / $ajax not working in all browsers

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I have code like below:

```
$('a.load-more').on("click",function(){
    $.get($('a.load-more').attr('href'), function(data) {
   $(".next-page").remove();
   $('.block-grid').append(data);
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

The html:

```
<li class="next-page">
<a href="http://example.com/ajax_all/" class="load-more">Load More →</a>
</li>
```

Which as you can see, takes the url of the ajax content from the .load-more  element, passes it to the $get method which then pulls in the content and appends it into the current page.

The odd thing is though, this is working in Chrome but not Firefox or Safari and there are no js errors in the inspectors for those browsers.

Instead of pulling the content in using ajax, it just goes to the url http://example.com/ajax_all/ and displays the content of that.

I'm stumped as to why it would work in Chrome and not Safari or firefox.

Comment: Your code is missing a `});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You script is invalid, or pasted wrong

```
$('a.load-more').on("click", function () {
    $.get($('a.load-more').attr('href'), function (data) {
        $(".next-page").remove();
        $('.block-grid').append(data);
        event.preventDefault();

});
```

After fixing that it shows that your `event.preventDefault();` is happening inside of the `get()` which is asynchronous.

```
$('a.load-more').on("click", function () {
   $.get($('a.load-more').attr('href'), function (data) {
      $(".next-page").remove();
      $('.block-grid').append(data);
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Placing the `preventDefault` outside of the call back should fix your problem.

```
$('a.load-more').on("click", function (e) {
    $.get($('a.load-more').attr('href'), function (data) {
        $(".next-page").remove();
        $('.block-grid').append(data);

    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the global `event` object, you should use the event parameter passed to the `click` event.

Comment: Hmm, now this is odd. When that page loads in the ajax content, it also loads in a new load more link that is exactly the same html as the initial one. But, this new link, when clicked doesn't load the ajax content, it just goes to the url of the ajax link. It's using jquery "on" so not sure why this is happening?

Comment: @John: `.on` doesn't magically make the event delegated.  To delegate an event, you bind it to a parent, and pass the element as a param: `$('#container').on('click', 'a.load-more', function(){`

Comment: @RocketHazmat I went with $(document).delegate('.load-more',) in the end which i guess is similar to what you were suggesting there?
It worked though so i'm really happy. Thanks a lot for all your help :)

Comment: @John: Yep, that's the same.  Though `on` is preferred in jQuery 1.8+.  `$(document).on('click', '.load-more', function(){`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Ah right ok, from reading up on "on" and "delegate" it seemed that they were the new "live". It looked like they were kind of for different things, not so much that one was better than the other. I need to do some more learning i think!! Thanks again!

Comment: @John: You're welcome!  Yeah, in the newest jQuery versions `.on()` is your one-stop shop for all your event binding needs.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the word event, it must be in the parameters of click callback.

Try that:

```
$('a.load-more').on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.get($('a.load-more').attr('href'), function(data) {
        $(".next-page").remove();
        $('.block-grid').append(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Some browsers (IE and Chrome) have a global `event` object, others don't.  So, yes, please use jQuery's provided event object.

Comment: Thanks, you would have got the tick if the guy above hadn't got there first. Really appreciate the answer though!